# pegar dados json em url e jogar dentro de uma textbox no c#

Tags: json, url, textbox

Boa tarde como faço para pegar os dados de uma url que esta no formato json e jogar dentro das minhas textbox ? obrigado

Answer (score 0):

boas Fernando

use a class JavaScriptSerializer para descerializar o Json.
tenta assim:

```
//GetResultViewModel é a class onde fica encapsulado os atributos do teu json
GetResultViewModel obj = new GetResultViewModel();
JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
obj = jss.Deserialize<GetResultViewModel>(teujson);
```

Comment: obg mas tem algum exemplo ?

Comment: coloca a estrutura do teu json pra poder lhe ajudar a descerializar

Comment: ola eu mandei la

Answer (score 0):

o link é esse
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

e como resultado da isso:

[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "2398.7", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1539760000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "39216435052.0", 
        "available_supply": "16349037.0", 
        "total_supply": "16349037.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-1.22", 
        "percent_change_24h": "4.64", 
        "percent_change_7d": "31.37", 
        "last_updated": "1495643052"
    }
]